# Ignoring apostrophes in stringified JSON object passed from controller to component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components, apostrophe

I am rendering a component passing down data this way from a parent controller. However, I am getting an error because apostrophes are being read as the end quote (i.e.

```
//Sample Object
var data = { "name": "Shelly O'brien", grade: 12}

 function template(data) {
      return $compile("<node componentdata='" + angular.toJson(data) + "'>
      </node>")($scope);
    }
```

Comment: I guess that you have to escape ' with \' and may be by using a regex.

Comment: @JonathanLebrun HTML doesn't use backslash for escaping, you need to convert to an entity like `&apos;`

Comment: @barmar : you are right. Good answer. Thanks for the correction

Comment: I suspect Angular has a better method for doing this, so you don't have to concatenate strings and parse them, instead creating an object and setting its attributes.